# How do I exclude the default named column having no data in my excelsheet which I am fetching in a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am having an excel sheet with multiple rows and columns which I am fetching it in a dataset in my .NET  application(using C#). When I see the returned dataset through a simple SELECT query, the excel sheet is having the required columns that I want and also there are some blank columns in between them which by default is given the name F1, F2, F3 and so on. What I want to do is remove these columns and only get the required columns that I want.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with DataTable and DataView:

```
DataTable oldTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
DataTable newTable = oldTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Only columns you want", "Only columns you want");
```

With all columns names dynamic you might try this:

```
for (int col = dataTable.Columns.Count - 1; col >= 0; col--)
{
  bool removeColumn = true;
  foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
  {
    if (!row.IsNull(col))
    {
      removeColumn = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (removeColumn)
    dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(col);
}
```

Or shorter LinQ version:

```
for (var col = dataTable.Columns.Count - 1; col >= 0; col--)
    {
        bool removeColumn = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().All(row => row.IsNull(col));
        if (removeColumn)
            dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(col);
    }
```

Comment: I cannot write directly the column names as I have to deal with them dynamically in my later part of the code.

Comment: Then try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766902/remove-all-columns-with-no-data-from-datatable

Comment: It was close but wasn't able to solve exactly what I was trying as the column names were not null but having some values by default eg. Emp ID., Emp Name, F1, F2, Salary, F4, Acc No. I need to remove F1, F2 and F4. Also the columns are dynamic every time I upload a new excel file.

Comment: And did you manage to get it working? I have tried it and it works for me.

Comment: Yes its working fine but later on I got stuck into another problem. My excel sheet contains some sub columns for some columns, and these blank sub columns are not getting removed

Answer (score 0):

@Yeronimo

your answer for dynamic columns is working fine... thank you very much sir...

and some related articles which might help

[Check if rows in an excel sheet are empty with asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951935/check-if-rows-in-an-excel-sheet-are-empty-with-asp-net)

[Remove Column From GridView While Converting To Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278510/remove-column-from-gridview-while-converting-to-excel)

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/297806/how-can-i-remove-empty-columns-in-spreadsheet